# How to correctly dispose System.Threading.Channels

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The subject says it all. Specifically, say I created `Channels` this  way.

```
Channel<byte[]> Stream { get; set; }

void Create() 
{
  Stream = System.Threading.Channels.Channel.CreateUnbounded<byte[]>();
}
```

**Question**

Is it ok to dispose it in the following order?

```
public virtual void Dispose()
{
  if (Stream.Writer.TryComplete()) // Dispose writer
  {
    Stream.Reader.Completion.ContinueWith(o => // Dispose reader
    {
      // Dispose the rest, e.g. some streaming server 

    }).Unwrap();
  }
}
```

P.S. In general, it works, but I'd like to make sure that if this code will be executed multiple times it won't cause memory leaks or unexpected runtime exceptions.

Comment: Why do you read and write a channel at the same place?

Comment: @shingo Because I have a server that allows external apps to send data to this server (Writer) and at the same time it subscribes to this updates (Reader) in order to generate some response - https://github.com/Indemos/Canvas/blob/main/Views/StreamServer.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your dispose method is correct because `TryComplete` returns true only once and it is thread safe.

But there is a problem, you expose the channel to subscribers, so they are able to explicitly call `TryComplete/Complete` to finish the writer. It's better to conceal it and just expose a write method.

```
public class StreamServer : IDisposable
{
    protected virtual Channel<byte[]> Stream { get; set; }
    public ValueTask WriteAsync(byte[] item) => Stream.Writer.WriteAsync(item);
}
```